# How changing Windows file-timestamp from filename-information?

Tags: mov

Facts:
If I've created many MOV videos with Digitalcamera or iPhone and have to work with this MOV-vids after later on (for example: rotation and/or converting to AVI, etc), then all 3 timestamps are overwritten in all these files with precisely those timestamps of conversion.
In the pictures I can read the EXIF-data and reset the timestamp with various programs even after processing. But with video-files it is not possible.

Problem: If I want to put it all together chronologically later in the PC, then (at least for the converted videos), the Create-date has gone (overwritten).

Attempted solution:
With longtime searching via GOOGLE I've found tons of video-converters - but not a single "safes" the primary Create-date.
So I take "BULK Rename Utility" before working with my videos I rename all files with this tool (feature: Create data via "Modified Current - DMY HMS"):

So with this I get eg. from DSCF3534.MOV (create date 08/05/2015 13:40:05) now a renamed file, named: 080515134005.MOV with timestamp from today (25/05/2015 15:00:00). With such filenames all chronological sorting later on will be possible.

Now the question to the batch / VBS experts:
Is there a way to change back the timestamp (Windows-Create-date) out of such a filename with real date/time-informations (080515134005.MOV) with easy commands?
Or does any one know an easy free Windows-Program to change timestamps out of informations inside the filename?